# How to publish a high resolution tif, jpg >50 MB with geoserver?

Tags: tiff, geoserver

I've a large size >50 MB tif with tfw file. I'd like to serve this with geoserver in my company. I did it, but the serve speed is very low, it's take 10 sec after zoom in and out.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some data prep to make the tiff more usable. I would convert to a GeoTIFF and add tiling, compression and overviews. So

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" outfile.tif infile.tif
```

and

```
gdaladdo -r average outfile.tif 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256
```

If you want to really go for it then I reccommend Paul Ramsey's blog post [GeoTiff Compression for Dummies](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html)